# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2017-03-18 19:22:51-07:00

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

I am relative new to Python Programming. When I try to standardize the data for Principle Components Analysis, I get the following error message.

Python version: 2.7.4.

```
df = pd.read_csv('E:/Downloads/Datasets/PCA_data.csv')
df.head()



  number_people                       date  timestamp  day_of_week  \
0             37  2015-08-14 17:00:11-07:00      61211            4   
1             45  2015-08-14 17:20:14-07:00      62414            4   
2             40  2015-08-14 17:30:15-07:00      63015            4   
3             44  2015-08-14 17:40:16-07:00      63616            4   
4             45  2015-08-14 17:50:17-07:00      64217            4   

   is_weekend  is_holiday  temperature  is_start_of_semester  \
0           0           0        71.76                     0   
1           0           0        71.76                     0   
2           0           0        71.76                     0   
3           0           0        71.76                     0   
4           0           0        71.76                     0   

   is_during_semester  month  hour  
0                   0      8    17  
1                   0      8    17  
2                   0      8    17  
3                   0      8    17  
4                   0      8    17 

x = df.iloc[:,1:8]  # all rows, all the features and no labels
y = df.iloc[:, 0]  # all rows, label only

# Scale the data to be between -1 and 1
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(x)
X

X = scaler.fit_transform(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-ce4e52c57a0a>", line 1, in <module>
    X = scaler.fit_transform(x)

  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 494, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 560, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 583, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2017-03-18 19:22:51-07:00
```

Please can someone look into it..Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a date column in there. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Thanks..I am gonna drop 'date' and 'timestamp' columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` column is a string and has no numerical value therefore you should not scale it. Furthermore you should also not consider the `timestamp` column because it is a continuously increasing value and you won't gain any meaningful information from it from PCA.

Therefore i'd recommend doing:

```
x = df.iloc[:,3:8]  # all rows, except label, date and timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

[StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) can only fit/transform float types as noted by the call to `check_array` with `dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES` in [StandardScaler.partial_fit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L611-L612).

You will need to either exclude your date column or convert it into a float format (unix timestamp) if you intend to include it in your analysis. Though I would recommend against including time as a feature altogether.

**NB** You also have the `timestamp` column that while capable of being transformed by `StandardScaler` should also be excluded from your data.